# CI with Jenkins MSB3202 Error while building job with subproject

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

I need some help from you.

In our team we want to build our .Net project in Jenkins. The project consists of subprojects that are added via the .csproj files. Now we have the problem that the Jenkins is thrown with the building of the individual subprojects due to the relative path, which is in the .sln file, following error:

MSB3202: The project file "xxxx..\xxx.csproj was not found. [C:xxxxx\x.sln]

Has anyone needed a solution like us to build our project structure to build every single project in Jenkins as a job? Or are there possible solutions for this error in Jenkins?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the  c# command line compiler instead of compiling main project with Visual Studio.  Build a batch file to do compiling.

Answer (score 0):

it s about msbuild.exe version. try to upgrade

choose upper version

[image]

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration ->  MSBuild

Add upper version like this

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "try to upgrade"?

Comment: Tried your approach with both versions but i'll get the same error